# Building a brand around a domain / word that has UK & American spellings

Tags: domains, branding

I'm trying to decide if I should run with an idea I have for a website, and the domain would contain a word that has an American and UK spelling.

I can only purchase one of the spellings. I've inquired about getting the other, but I am doubtful that I could get it at this point.

Is it still worth it to centre a brand / domain around a single spelling?

Answer (score 2):

You would not have a brand by having 2 different spellings.

A brand should be easily identifiable. Having different spellings will lead to confusion and will lead to emotional detachment to the brand.

That being said, if you wish to target the USA & the UK, I would suggest rethinking your brand name and have something that works for both cultures. Not only will it save you from the hassle of buying different domains, it will be more cohesive and easily identifiable by people.